# Write RSS Feed with Java and STAX - How to make it dynamic?

Tags: java, rss

I have written a java program that will generate an rss feed. What I am having trouble figuring out is how do I make this available to my users in such a way that the feed is generated on demand? The data will change constantly and I want them to see the latest when they bring up the feed. I am likely missing something obvious. This will be on a Tomcat 7 server in a Spring web app. Thanks!

Comment: um, just generate the feed on each web call?

Comment: I know I sound lame here, but bear with me, please. We have a PHP intranet site that allows users to subscribe to various .rss feeds. My java program creates such a feed, by pulling data from a database that is updated often. If the user is pointing to the .rss file, then do I need a scheduler or something to run the java program to create the .rss file over and over so it's got recent data? I am not getting how the .rss file will be generated, just by the user accessing it.

Comment: do you want the rss feed to be generated on each call, or do you just want to serve up a static file which is periodically refreshed?

Comment: Generated on each call, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

presumably you want to write a servlet which generates the rss feed on each request.  is there more to your question?